# How to check if Task thread is blocked

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

I have a WebAPI webservice that is running into a bottleneck, whenever many requests to get one long-running Database operation comes, all other requests take way longer than normal to finish.

The webservice has each end-point as follows:

```
            var result = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return _coordinator.GetValue(key);
            });

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
```

where _coordinator is class injected via Constructor that will call a service (non-web service) that will fetch data from the database (long-running). _coordinator may call several long-running service calls which in turn will fetch from database.

From my understanding, Task.Run will create a task that will be ran in a thread from the thread pool. But I'm not certain if those threads are being blocked when they could be freed.

So I'd like to get the thread running the coordinator code and see if it's blocked or if it's released to the Thread Pool until the machine service returns.

Comment: Threads are an ample resource. It is very unlikely that you are constrained on the number of threads. Sounds like your database is merely overloaded. Optimize the query.

Comment: Is the `_coordiantor` a third party or it is your own?

Comment: _coordinator is our own class. It's a pass-through. It calls Middleware Service to fetch from Oracle DB.

Comment: Is `GetValue()` async? In other words, what is its return type?

Comment: @svick, it's not async, it returns a data model from the database. And we're talking about thousands of concurrent connections.

Comment: @abug you could always use the [ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/) and pass one of the custom schedulers from this library to `Task.Factory.StartNew` so you could directly observe the threads in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `GetValue()` is a synchronous method, the ThreadPool thread used by `Task.Run()` will be used for the whole time the method executes.

If you're worried about the number of threads your code uses (and since you say you can have many concurrent requests, that is a valid worry), then you should make `GetValue()` truly asynchronous. To do that, you will need to call the service asynchronously. How exactly to do that depends on how are you calling the service, but generally it involves changing `foo.Bar()` into `await foo.BarAsync()`.

---

Also, since your code is a webservice, it's already running on a ThreadPool thread, there is no reason to use `Task.Run()` to switch to another thread (and then use `await` to release the first one).